# Building Debian package without upstream

Tags: linux, git, build, debian, package

I'm replacing a hacky Debian package build script with http://jenkins-debian-glue.org/, which uses `git-buildpackage`.

The `generate-git-snapshot` script runs this monster of a line:

```
gbp buildpackage  -nc --git-force-create --git-ignore-new --git-ignore-branch -S -us -uc --git-verbose --git-builder=/bin/true --git-cleaner=/bin/true --git-export-dir=
```

This fails every time with an error: `gbp:error: upstream/1.0.0 is not a valid treeish`. 1.0.0 is the initial version string in `debian/changelog`, but the `upstream` branch doesn't exist.

I'm not quite sure what to do about the `upstream` branch - this package is not a fork of an existing project, it's a Git repo that's only meant to build a Debian package.

How can/should I build the package?

Answer (score 1):

Unless your packaging is very old, it's probably a `3.0 (quilt)` package. If that's the case, gbp is looking for separate branches for upstream source and Debian-specific customizations so that it can prepare the source package correctly.

Since you're building a native package, [`debian/source/format`](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/dother.en.html#sourcef) needs to be changed to `3.0 (native)`.